# Animated movie with a boy inventing (and losing) a future-viewing machine, later meets his future son

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I have watched an animated movie a year ago where a boy invents a sort of time machine where people can see their past and future in it. But then his machine gets lost or something (I don't actually remember).

Later he meets his son who jumps from the future and helps him to get back his machine after numerous fights and adventures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like ["Meet the Robinsons"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_the_Robinsons) (2007).

[image: cartoon characters and a dinosaur]

A boy named Lewis invents a machine that can show you memories of the past.  It gets stolen, then another boy shows up (from the future) with a time machine.  Lewis turns out to be the other boy's father.

Lewis eventually gets his machine back and goes on to become a famous inventor and scientist, and eventually builds the time machine that his son uses to help him recover his memory machine.

Along the way, Lewis and the other kid stop a crazy guy named Goon from taking over the world with his robotic bowler hat (actually one of Lewis' failed inventions) and the stolen memory machine.

Comment: Thanks for the title. Yes, this is the movie I was looking for.